# Tool for quick generation of ASP.Net-pages for editing database tables-dictionaries and master-detail related tables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to add a large amount of stereotyped pages to my ASP.Net Web-project.
Is there any tool for quick generation ASP.Net pages on which we can edit simple database table-dictionaries or master-detail related tables? (database - Firebird or MySQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a scaffold generator.

[Microsoft - Dynamic Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469.aspx)

[Subsonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/)

Answer (score 2):

How about .Net Dynamic Data?

The training videos can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/).

Watching just the first one should be enough to tell you if it's what you're looking for.  I just did my first site using it, and it took me several hours to watch all the videos, and one hour to get the site up and customized the way I wanted it.